# Apache 2.4 mod_dav_svn configuration file

Tags: apache, svn

I am trying to Setup Server dictated configurations on my Subversion repository which is served by an Apache 2.4 server.

Based on the information I found one has to alter the SVN configuration file on the server but which one is used by the mod_dav_svn module of the Apache Server?
I already tried different ones (Admin, Public) but none worked.

Does anybody know which configuration file is used by this module?

Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am refering to a configuration file for the svn server itself. If svnserve is used one can place a svnserve.conf file in .svn folder of a repository which contains configurations for the repository like password storage or allowed users. Is such a file available for mod_dav_svn?

Answer (score 0):

As I know the SVN config file is the user and not to the server. The only things you have to do is give apache user write permission on svn repo and config the apache.

Here is a example of apache config file, repo available at http://mysserver/SVN_REPO1

```
LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so

<IfModule mod_dav_svn.c>
Alias /SVN_REPO "/PATH_TO/SVN_REPO"

<Location /SVN_REPO1>
DAV svn
SVNPath "/PATH_TO/SVN_REPO"
SVNPathAuthz Off # More faster but don't check permission permission in all parenth path ( - security)
AuthzSVNAccessFile "/path_to_/authz"
require valid-user
Satisfy Any
Options MultiViews
Require all granted

</Location>
```